# A $2\times2$ ColorSaw

Tags: logical-deduction, visual

The pieces of this ColorSaw have been flipped, rotated and moved.

Can you reassemble the puzzle so that each adjacent side has the same color/shape?

[image: ColorSaw22_1]

Please explain your logic!

Comment: what is a colorsaw? thanks!

Comment: It's like a JigSaw, but with colors not jigs.@OmegaKrypton

Comment: Is Tetravex the original name btw?

Answer (score 5):

> Looks possible to me.
>  
>  1. Rotate the top left square by 90 degrees clockwise
>  
>  2. Rotate the bottom left square by 90 degrees counterclockwise.
>  
>  You'll get this picture:
>  
>  [image]
>  
>  3. Keep the top left square where it is and shuffle the other three around:
>  
>  [image]
>  
>  I'm afraid not much logic was involved - I started trying to show that it's impossible and came up with a counterexample :-)

Answer (score 4):

Second solution with each symbol matched.
I wasn't happy with my first solution because the red stars are not oriented the same.
This is simpler and more pleasing:

> - slide top right down
>  - slide bottom right across
>  - slide bottom left up
>  - slide top left across and rotate 90° clockwise
>
>  - if one **must** be flipped, let's flip the one with 2 red stars because it is symmetrical
>
>  [image]

My solution

> matches one of each pair
>
>  - bottom left stays put
>  - top left slides to bottom right
>  - bottom right slides up and rotates 90° anti-clockwise
>  - top right slides left, flips vertically and rotates 90° clockwise
>
>  [image]